# How can I save two child value using pipe from single parents

Tags: c, pipe, fork

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int s1 = 0, s2=0, s3=0;
    int n= atoi(argv[1]);
    pid_t  child1, child2,wpid;
    int status = 0 ;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd)< 0){
        printf("An error ocurred with opening the pipe\n");
    }

    child1 = fork();

    if(child1<0){
        printf("Fork Failed for child 1.\n");
    }else if(child1 == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        while(count<=n){
            if(count%2 == 0){
                s1 = s1 + count;
                
            }
                count = count + 1;

        }
        // printf("%d \n", s1);
        write(fd[1], &s1, sizeof(int));
        close(fd[1]);
    }else{
        child2 = fork();
        if(child2<0){
            printf("failed to fork child 2.");
        }
        if(child2 == 0){
            while(count2<=10){
                if(count2%2 != 0){
                    s2 = s2 + count2;
                }
                count2 = count2 +1;

            }
            write(fd[1], &s2, sizeof(int));
            close(fd[1]);
        }else{
            while((wpid = wait(&status))>0);
            read(fd[0], &s3, sizeof(int));
            printf("s3 %d\n", s3);
            close(fd[0]);
            
        }
        // close(fd[1]);
        // read(fd[0], &s3, sizeof(int));
        // close(fd[0]);
    }

    return 0;


}
```

As you can see from the code I am trying to save s1 and s2 value using pipe but i cant save both of the value. Child1 value is always replace with the value of child2 is there anyway I can save both without over writing the other one. receive the both value in parent process and get the sum of s1 and s2 and add them in parent process.

Comment: You need a separate pipe for each child.

Comment: Also, look at posix_spawn() as a faster alternative to fork().